# Trying to read from multiple columns and write to multiple columns Python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, openpyxl

I am wanting to read from excel workbook Calavi multiple columns and then write all the data to Shelda.  However it keeps giving me:

```
for row in range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,worksheet.max_row):
TypeError: range expected at most 3 arguments, got 6
```

Is it not entirely possible to use multiple columns?

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\WW\CALAVI.xlsx')
first_sheet = wb.get_sheet_names()[0]
worksheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)


for row in range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,worksheet.max_row):
    for column in "1, 2, 3, 4, 5":  
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
        worksheet[cell_name].value
        for i in range(3, 8):
            ws1.cell(row=i, column=5).value=temp[0]
data = [list('abcd'), list('efgh')]
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\WW\SHELDA.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    for k, val in enumerate(line):
        sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=k+1).value = val
wb.save('C:\WW\SHELDA.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you're seeing occurs because of improper use of the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) object. If you want to loop through all row numbers, then replace the line

```
for row in range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,worksheet.max_row):
```

with this:

```
for row in range(1, worksheet.max_row + 1):
```